# What is the religous significance of this hadith?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, history

[Hadith 116](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/3) in Sahih al-Bukharis collection is narrated by Abdullah bin Umar; he says:

> Once the Prophet (ﷺ) led us in the `Isha' prayer during the last days of his life and after finishing it (the prayer) (with Taslim) he said: "Do you realize (the importance of) this night?" Nobody present on the surface of the earth tonight will be living after the completion of one hundred years from this night."

This is an awesome thought; but it is true of every night; most people living on this planet today will not be alive in a hundred years time; that is of the six or seven billion people alive right now on the surface of this earth only a handful will be alive a century later; we may as well say no-one, as handful out of so many is hardly any; thus this generation will have fallen; but another will have risen to have taken its place; at least that is the literal meaning that I see in this hadith.

The Prophet (pbuh) says *this night*, presumably *the* night this hadith was recorded; not this night, the night following the day that I'm writing this; is there a deeper significance to this hadith or is the literal reading the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

He said *nobody* would be alive, not even that handful of people.